# Remove Gnome Components detect by Packagename

Tags: process, gnome, apt, dpkg

I have tried out the `dpkg`, `aptitude` and `apt` commands.
On the gnome desktop I decided to remove one component.

```
 sudo apt-get remove gnome-games
```

or something else, all works fine.

But if I don’t know the right package-name I get in trouble.

This can help me to find out PID.

```
 gnome-system-monitor
```

But now I also didn’t know the right process name, because they are very short.

How can I find out the right packagename if I start an application in gnome?

**Edit (8.Nov.2014)**

I think a mix from difference applikation are the best way.

Show the pocesses that are run and the process-name

```
gnome-system-monitor
```

Search for packagename

```
 dpkg -l 'gnome-*'
 dpkg -l | grep 'gnome-'
 aptitude search gnome-*
```

Search full Package List

```
 apt-cache search gnome*
```

Use Synaptic (UI-Paket Manager)

```
 /usr/bin/synaptic-pkexec
```

Comment: `apt-cache search some-name` Or if you want to know about utilites try `dpkg -S $(which prog_name)`

Answer (score 0):

You can find package providing a command by `dpkg -S`:

From manpage:

```
-S, --search filename-search-pattern...
              Search for packages that own files corresponding to the  given  pattern.   Standard  shell
              wildchars  can  be used in the pattern.  This command will not list extra files created by
              maintainer scripts, nor will it list alternatives.
```

By running `dpkg -S <command>`, you can find what packages (and it's files) providing this command/programme